# Java - Concatenate Consecutive Elements in a Stream

Tags: java, java-stream, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two consecutive elements in an array. I could do this iteratively, but I am trying to learn Java Streams, and thought this would be a good exercise.

If I have an array of Strings:
`String exampleArray[] = ["a1", "junk", "a2", "b1", "junk", "b2", "c1", "junk", "junk", "junk", "c2", "d1", "junk", "d2", "junk-n"]`

I want to get:
`["a1 - a2", "b1 - b2", "c1 - c2", "d1 - d2"]` as output.

I tried this:

```
Arrays.asList(exampleArray)
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> s.length() > 0)   // gets rid of blanks
    .filter(s -> !s.contains("junk"))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / 2))
    .values();
```

This returns a `Collection<List<String>>` like `[ [a1, a2], [b1, b2], [c1, c2], [d1, d2] ]`

But I am not sure how to get to: `["a1 - a2", "b1 - b2", "c1 - c2", "d1 - d2"]`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not `groupBy` the first character of the string? How is it that you divide by `2` and still have those many groups?

Comment: my data doesn't have 'a1', 'a2' - that was just as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. You already had the pairs, all you have to do now is smash them with a "-" in the middle into a String.

Give this a try:

```
Arrays.stream(exampleArray)
                .filter(s -> s.length() > 0)   // gets rid of blanks
                .filter(s -> !s.contains("junk"))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / 2))
                .values()
                .stream()                        //stream the pairs
                .map(l -> String.join("-", l))   //and put a "-" between them & into a string
                .collect(Collectors.toList())    //collect all your joined String
```

Comment: Thank you! I just didn't think of using the `.map` over all strings in the inner lists!

Comment: @banncee, np. Anytime you want or need to "convert", "transform", or go from one type to another, think of "map".

Answer (score 2):

Collectors.groupingBy has a overloaded method where you can pass the result to a downstream collector. In fact, by default it has used toList collector and so you got List. You can use joiningBy to concatenating strings.

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / 2
       , Collectors.joining(" - ")))
```

Result is

```
[a1-a2, b1-b2, c1-c2, d1-d2]
```

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String exampleArray[] = new String[] {"a1", "junk", "a2", "b1", "junk", "b2", "c1", "junk", "junk", "junk", "c2", "d1", "junk", "d2", "junk-n"};
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    Collection<String> ans = (Arrays.asList(exampleArray)
            .stream()
            .filter(s -> s.length() > 0)   // gets rid of blanks
            .filter(s -> !s.contains("junk"))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / 2, Collectors.joining(" - ")))
            .values());

    System.out.println(ans);
}
```

Comment: This causes a type issue; `The method collect(Supplier<R>, BiConsumer<R,? super String>, BiConsumer<R,R>) in the type Stream<String> is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<Object,?,Map<Object,List<Object>>>, Collector<CharSequence,capture#2-of ?,String>)`

Comment: @banncee It's a bit odd because it works for me without any issue. I updated the answer with full code. Did you do anything different ?

Comment: This worked for me too, I'm not sure what happened either. This is admittedly cleaner and less verbose than my answer and what I would use in a real app. When I answered, my thought process was more in the "step-by-step" mind frame so it was easier to explain the "chain" steps.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this output is:

```
String a[] = {"a1", "junk", "a2", "b1", "junk", "b2", "c1", "junk", "junk", "junk", "c2", "d1", "junk", "d2", "junk-n"};

    Arrays.parallelSort(a); //sorting the array from a to z
    
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        
        if(a[i].matches(".*\\d.*")) //verifying if have a number in string
           output.add(a[i] + " - " + a[++i]);
        
    }
    
    System.out.println(output); //["a1 - a2", "b1 - b2", "c1 - c2", "d1 - d2"]
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - the data is for illustrative purposes only. Normally, they will be random text.